# Basic Ideal Op Amp Circuit Analysis

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I am trying to familiarize myself with operational amplifiers by going through [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072320842) by Sergio Franco.

This is a basic question regarding the example given on page 16, which I am struggling to understand.

[image]

According to the explanation, V3 is equal to -6V.

I know that **when operated with negative feedback, an ideal op amp will output whatever voltage and current it takes to drive VD to zero, or equivalently, to force VN to track VP.**

The top half of the circuit looks like an inverting amplifier circuit, with the bottom half leaving Vp (Voltage at positive input) at 0:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why you say that according to the explanation it should be -6v?

Comment: Oh I see. You’re ignoring the 10k resistor

Comment: @Undertalk Re. your first comment, the book states that the Vout = -6V

Comment: as v1=v2, the 30k has 6v across it, which draws a current I1 through itself and therefore through the 10k resistor, so v1 is not zero volts.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This helped me understand further.

Comment: Why do you think that you are "doing wrong"? The result is OK!

Comment: \$\small i_1 = 0.2 mA\$, so \$\small v_1 = -2 V\$; hence \$\small v_o\$ relative to ground is \$\small v_0=-4-2=-6 V\$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's perform the calculations to verify the explanation.

Since \$v1=v2\$ the 30kΩ resistor has the entire 6V from the generator across it, hence the current:

$$
i=\frac{6V}{30k\Omega}=0.2mA
$$

Since the opamp inputs (ideally) draw no current, this is the same current flowing in the 10kΩ resistor. Therefore, because the current direction is from ground to \$v1\$, we have:

$$
v_1 = - i \cdot 10k\Omega = -0.2mA \cdot 10k\Omega = -2V
$$

We already know that \$v1=v2=-2V\$ because of the opamp action (virtual short between inputs) due to negative feedback. Moreover the same current \$i\$ flows in the 20kΩ resistor, hence we can write:

$$
v_3 = v_2 - 20k\Omega \cdot i 
= -2V - 20k\Omega \cdot 0.2mA 
= -2V - 4V = -6V
$$

In the end your conclusion is right. I hope this explicit calculation procedure dissipates any residual doubt you have.